# Sliding weighted randomization from number range?

Tags: ruby, random

When picking a random number from a range, I'm doing `rand(0..100)`. That works all well and good, but I'd like it to favor the lower end of the range.

So, there's the highest probability of picking `0` and the lowest probability of picking `100` (and then everything in between), based on some weighted scale.

How would I implement that in Ruby?

Comment: What do you mean with "some weighted scale"?

Comment: What you want is a "non-uniform discrete probability distribution". There are infinitely many such distributions, so you need to pick one before we can give you a sensible answer i.e. you need to decide how likely each number should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer concerns the generation of random variates from underlying probability distributions generally, not just those distributions that give greater weight to smaller random variates.

You need to identify a (probability) density function `f` that has has the desired shape. Then construct its (cumulative) distribution function `F` and the latter's inverse function `G` (the *quantile*), meaning that `G(F(x)) = x` for all `x` in the sample space. `f` can be  continuous or discrete.

For example, `f` and `F` could be the (negative) exponential density and distribution functions, which give higher weight to smaller values, as shown below (source: [Wiki for Exponential Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)).

[image: Exponential PDF][image: Exponential CDF]

<sup>**Exponential PDF**</sup>                                                <sup>**Exponential CDF**</sup>

These functions are given by f(x) = λe<sup>−λx</sup> and F(x) = 1 − e<sup>−λx</sup>, respectively, where `e` is the base of natural logarithms. `λ` is a *shape parameter*.

To generate random variates for this distribution we would draw a (pseudo-) random number between 0 and 1, mark that on the vertical axis of the CDF graph and draw a horizontal line from that point. The random variate is the point on the horizontal axis where the CDF intersects the horizontal line. If y is the random number between 0 and 1, we have

```
y = 1 − e**(−λx)
```

Solving for `x`,

```
x = -log(1 - y)/λ
```

so the inverse CDF is seen to be

```
g(y) = -log(1 - y)/λ
```

Here are some random variates for `λ = 1`.

```
def g(y)
  -Math.log(1 - y)
end

5.times { y = rand; puts "y = #{y.round(2)}, x = #{g(y).round(2)}" }
y = 0.09, x = 0.10
y = 0.67, x = 1.09
y = 0.35, x = 0.43
y = 0.55, x = 0.79
y = 0.19, x = 0.21
```

Most CDFs do not have closed-form inverse functions, but if the CDF is continuous, a binary search can be performed to compute an arbitrarily-close approximation to the random variate (`x` on the graph) for a given `y = rand`.

The [Weibull Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) is one of the few other continuous distributions (besides uniform and triangular) that has a closed-form inverse function. Having two parameters, it offers greater scope than the single-parameter exponential distribution for modelling a desired shape.

For discrete CDFs, one can use `if` statements (or, better, a case statement) to compute the random variate for a given `y = rand`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try taking the lower of two random numbers.  That would favour smaller numbers.

```
[rand(0..100), rand(0..100)].min
```

If your first number is 5, the chances of your second number being lower (and replacing) is only 4 in 100.

If your first number is 95, the chances of your second number being lower is 94 out of 100 so it's likely to be replaced with the lower number.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
low_end_of_range = 1
high_end_of_range = 100
weighted_range = []

(low_end_of_range..high_end_of_range).each do |num|
  weight = (high_end_of_range - num) + 1

  weight.times do
    weighted_range << num
  end
end

weighted_range.sample
```

This will give:

- 1 the *highest* probability of being picked, as it would appear 100 times in the `weighted_range` array,
- 2 the *second highest* probability of being picked, as it would appear 99 times in the `weighted_range` array,
- 100 the *lowest* probability of being picked, as it would appear only once in the `weighted_range` array, and
- 99 the *second lowest* probability of being picked, as it would appear twice in the `weighted_range` array,
- etc.

---

And if you don't need any flexibility in the size of your sampling (i.e. `low_end_of_range` / `high_end_of_range`), you can do it in a nice one-liner:

```
(1..100).map { |i| (101 - i).times.map { i } }.flatten.sample
```